# Importing scala packages (no jar) at Zeppelin

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

This about running Spark/Scala from a Zeppelin notebook.

In order to better modularize and reorganize code, I need to import existing Scala classes, packages or functions into the notebook, preferably skipping creating a jar file (much the same as in PySpark).

Something like:

```
import myclass
```

where 'myclass' is implemented in a .scala file. Probably this source code needs to reside in a specific location for Zeppelin.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's no such feature in zeppelin.

Answer (score 0):

The only way of doing what you propose is to add a `jar` to Spark's classpath jars. At least, that's how I'm using it.

I wouldn't recommend the practice of importing scala classes from somewhere in a `.scala` file. That code should be packaged and made available for all workers, such as in all cluster workers and master.